# Flipping Tab bar to a simple view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, flip, tabbarcontroller

1. Is it possible to flip the tab bar view to another view? If no, please answer me with 'No'.
2. If it is possible, could you give me the basic idea how to do it? I tried some ways but it did not work, and I am a beginner.

Comment: Sorry. that was partly because I did not get the exact answer, or I forgot to mark as answer. But I often get quick help from previous questions here in Stack OverFlow. I think your answer could benefit a lot of people who may find it through Google.

Comment: You should still work on this so when people link to this page, they can clearly see which answer is correct. And Darren's answer below is correct.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I tested it and it worked. It's not that I would not accept answers, I meant I will. Some cases I forgot to do so, and some cases I got no answers at all or the answer was not what I wanted. If I mark the answer as correct, then it may confuse others. Anyways, I from this time, I will take more care not to forget to mark the correct answers.

Comment: No hard feelings! I'm just trying to ensure that your continued use of Stack Overflow goes smoothly for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you have a tab bar and you want to flip the entire screen to another view? You can do this with modal view controllers. For example (from a view controller in the tab bar controller):

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hey..., wow! It worked. This is exactly what I wanted, and the answer was so simple. I had tried a lot of codes in vain, like pushing the view controller, performing a segue... Thanks.